# Фиксированный фон для Safari браузера

Tags: javascript, css, ios, вёрстка, safari

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать чтобы фоновое изображение сайта (`backgound`) в браузере Safari было фиксированным. На компе в браузерах нормально работает `background-attachment`, а на Safari — нет.

```
#container-body {
  padding: 0;
  background: url(images/bg-body.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-attachment: !important;
}
```

Comment: А чё так? Согласно документации должно работать http://caniuse.com/#search=background-attachment Попробуй !important использовать

Comment: @blackstar1991 не получается что то или в коде что то не так?

Comment: Погоди, а мы с тобою про одно и тоже Safari говорим? Просто если ты про мобильную версию для IOS, то оно там с каким то ограничениями, или вообще не действует. Вообщем в документации что-то такое написано

Comment: Я про мобильную Safari))

Comment: @Дмитрий А причём тут JavaScript и jQuery к вопросу? И укажите, пожалуйста, в самом вопросе, что речь идёт про мобильную Safari под iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мобильный Safari не поддерживает это свойство из-за проблем с производительностью. Без JS для мобильных Safari делал решение на основе `position: fixed;`. То есть, вместо:

```
body {
    background: url("../images/bg.jpg") no-repeat 50% / cover fixed;
}
```

Делаем:

```
body:before {
    background: url("../images/bg.jpg") no-repeat 50% / cover;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Подробности в можно найти в этой статье: https://habrahabr.ru/post/282079/